# jQuery Mobile - slider cannot be moved

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, leaflet

I am  using a jQuery slider but I cannot move the handle.

The HTML structure:

```
<div id="map" class="map" style="position: relative;">
  <div id="legend" class="legend" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; width:300px; z-index: 100;">
    <div style="width:290px; height: 150px; padding: 5px;">
      <label class="checkbox-label"><input name="gai_max_V" id="gai_max_V" class="runoff" type="checkbox"><image src="icons/icona_land_use.png"/><p id="legend_text">Soil Runoff Capacity (1955)</p></input></label>
      <div id="div-slider">
        <input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="80" min="20" max="100" step="20" data-highlight="true">
      </div>
    <div style="width:290px; height: 150px; padding: 5px;">...</div>
    <div style="width:290px; height: 150px; padding: 5px;">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery mobile version is 1.4.5 and the map, that is the content of the parent div is created by Leaflet:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: [45.81, 9.1],
  zoom: 15
});
```

Can you guess why I cannot move the handle?

Thanks,

Eylul

Comment: It's best you show all your relevant code, eg: how do you initialize your slider etc...

Comment: Actually, this is it, I just put it inside the html, and then I attach an event listener, but I don't think it is relevant. By the way, thanks for checking the question :)

Comment: Unable to reproduce, as you can see here: http://imgur.com/ZebN41a using the following example on Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/oLMCHGlOOmzZWf1CclIh/

Comment: your example in my case doesn't work @iH8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with small css hack.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/u2j24x25/2/

```
<!-- Insert this part after MAP --> 
<div id="div-slider"><input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="80" min="20" max="100" step="20" data-highlight="false"></div>

/* CSS */
#map { height: 380px; } #div-slider {z-index:99999999;border:1px solid red;} #div-slider {position:relative;top:-250px;width:300px;float:right}
```

Edit: 
Putting div#legend after div#map will solve that problem.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/u2j24x25/4/

```
<div id="map" class="map" style="position: relative;">
</div>

<div id="legend" class="legend" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; width:300px; z-index: 100;">
    <div style="width:290px; height: 150px; padding: 5px;">
      <label class="checkbox-label">
      <input name="gai_max_V" id="gai_max_V" class="runoff" type="checkbox"><image src="icons/icona_land_use.png"/><p id="legend_text">Soil Runoff Capacity (1955)</p></input></label>
      <div id="div-slider">
        <input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="80" min="20" max="100" step="20" data-highlight="true">
      </div>
    <div style="width:290px; height: 150px; padding: 5px;">...</div>
    <div style="width:290px; height: 150px; padding: 5px;">...</div>
  </div>
</div>

/* CSS */
#map { height: 380px; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see that putting the slider outside map div works. But I need that when I scroll the legend, the slider moves with other elements. At the end there will be a slider for each layer inside the legend div. Is there a way to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Try to put legend div after closing map div. I will update answer with new demo.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
Then I also had to remove these lines:
L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(L.DomUtil.get('legend'));
L.DomEvent.disableScrollPropagation(L.DomUtil.get('legend'));

Comment: I didn't use this lines in my demo, that's why i have no idea for what they are :) You are welcome.